# How to properly add admin user to a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

Let's say I have an endpoint for posting new users with a logic like this:

```
    ...
    user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ['name', 'email', 'password', 'isAdmin']));
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

    await user.save();

    const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    ...
```

This would work but now of course every user could set the `isAdmin` flag. Another way would be adding admin users manually to the database but this is probably not the best way.

Is there a recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: create 1 `superadmin` manually in DB, and that `superadmin` can add `isAdmin` = 1 (subadmin) from their login, and from here you can register normal users so here` isAdmin` = 0

Comment: Souds good to me! If you would answer this, I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below:

Step 1  : Create one `superadmin` manually give `isAdmin` = 2

Step 2 : Above created `superadmin` can only add/register sub admin, give `isAdmin` = 1

Step 3:  And last, from normal regostration, you can give `isAdmin` = 0

so `isAdmin` = 2 (superadmin), `isAdmin` = 1 (subadmin) and `isAdmin` = 0 (normal user)

**Note**: 2,1 value for `isAdmin` is my suggestion, you can change if you want as per your requirements.

Comment: I think it is better to count the other way, this is easier to add more permissions level in the future (superadmin = 0, admin = 1, ...). In fact, the superadmin user isn't supposed to move, because he will always be the highest user in the db, so setting him to 0 makes him stay at the same place, regardless the other permission levels

Comment: @valfur03 yes, that's why i give NOTE , you can change value as per your need, even you can add separate table for user type for more use.

Answer (score 1):

As @Devsi Odedra mentionned, you can add a **superadmin** user (say level 0) manually in your database, or using **JS** script (`node initDb.js` for example).

Then, whenever a user wants to add another user, you can just check that he is not adding a user with same privileges, that each user can only add a user with `n + 1`. This way, the superadmin user will on be able to add users with a `level >= 1`, and so on.